# Create Project Template in Adobe Premiere cs6

Tags: premiere

I'm a youtuber and I make a bunch of videos. Every time I make a vid I have to import the same files [watermarks, back ground music]. Is there anyway to make a template so when I create a new file they are already there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly - you can simply create a new project with the appropriate files already imported. Save that project. Whenever you need to create a new video, go to your template project and save it as a copy. This way, you retain your original template and you can bypass the process of reimporting the necessary media.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with nested sequences.  I will have to double check if it is possible to import a Premiere sequence from one project in to another, (I normally use After Effects for this kind of thing.) however you can produce a sequence that has your watermarks and music and leaders and such and then simply sub-out the underlying nested sequence with whatever your latest project is.

This allows for you to reuse the shared components while only having to adjust for any change in length of the main sequence.